# What is the order of $\{0\} \times \mathbb Z_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the order of $\{0\} \times \mathbb Z_4$?

Not really sure what the order of this is?

$\{0\} \times \mathbb Z_4$ would be ?

$(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3)$? $4$?

Comment: I believe that is the context my text is speaking of.

Comment: Do you know the definition of order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've correctly listed the elements in $\{0\} \times \mathbb Z_4$, followed by the order of the group:

$$\{0\} \times \mathbb Z_4 = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (0,2), (0,3)\} \implies |\{0\} \times \mathbb Z_4| = 4$$

Note that the order of the group also follows from the fact that $$|\{0\} \times \mathbb Z_4| = 1 \times 4 = |\{0\}| \times |\mathbb Z_4|$$

Answer (score 3):

The order of a group is the number of elements it contains.  The cartesian product of finite groups $A,B$ has cardinality equal to the product of the cardinalities of $A,B$ respectively.  The trivial group $\{0\}$ has one element, while $\mathbb{Z}_4$ has four elements.  Consequently, the cartesian product $\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ has four elements, and thus order 4.

Answer (score 3):

It is not hard seeing that for groups $G$ and $H$ then $$e_H\times G=\{(e_H,g)\mid g\in G\}\cong G$$ For this, define $$\phi:~G\to H\times G\\ \phi(g)=(e_H,g)$$ and show that $\phi$ is a well-defined injective and $G\cong\phi(G)=e_H\times G$. Now lets doing some codes in GAP for your sample $\{0\}\times\mathbb Z_4$:

```
gap> Z4:=CyclicGroup(4);;
     StructureDescription(DirectProduct(Group(Identity(Z4)),Z4));
```

---

```
"C4"
```

Comment: I see you often use the software GAP and this encourages me to try to learn it. +1 ;-)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I am new in it Sami, but I am ready to help you with all I have learned about it. :)

Comment: Thank you for your availability and your generosity. I'll try to read some GAP's document from the net  and I would not hesitate to ask for help when needed.;-)